# Django Form from Model in pure Python

Tags: python, django, oop, orm, sqlalchemy

#### Intro

I'm trying to create interface to provide easy access to online game data. There are some basic parameters of each hero in the database, created with HeroModel class (using SQLAlchemy).

#### Problem

Also there is need to create *Manager* class above the Model to change data in its instance (in the *Manager*), but not in the database. The only way to implement this, as I see now is to rewrite all the Model fields to *Manager* class.

"Form from Model" mechanism seems like right solution for me.

#### Question

How can I implement this idea in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem but if you want to get an instance from the database and change its attributes without but don't save the changes in the database you can do so freely as long as you don't call `.save` on the object.

For an example:

```
hero = Hero.objects.get(pk=1)  # Get the instance from the database
hero.name = "My Super Hero"
hero.save()  # Here you are changing the attributes and saving to the database

hero.name = "Actually a villain"
hero.power = 200  
hero.life = 90
hero.life = 80  # All of these changes are NOT reflected to the database

hero = Hero.objects.get(pk=1)  # Reload the same instance from database
print(hero.name)  # Outputs "My Super Hero" because other changes were not saved
```

Comment: You understood me right. I realised this opportunity, but thought it is not reliable or something like this. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: There's solution I was looking for: [setattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) makes the trick: I can get all the columns names and after that create class attributes with such names.